# Reordering a name file in linux/ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, filenames

I'm trying for a time now to have the titles of some(1 to 3 hundred) musics changed, using bash script or commands like rename or sed, along with regex, but I failed miserably, probably because I'm new to the word of programming and terminal commands. That's what I need help:


The Songs have the same pattern:
'***String1*** *String2* **String3**.mp3'
Examples:
'***Bakemonogatari*** *Ost* **Classmate**.mp3'
'***Kizumonogatari*** *ost* **Jigoku no Sata mo Kane Shidai**.mp3'

The ***String1*** will always end with the suffix 'monogatari', I think this is the way to search for this piece of string.
The *String2* can be capitalized or not.
The **String3** is the actual name of the song, and can have names with spaces in-between. 
Obs1. I think the way to select both the ***String1*** and **String3** is through *String2*, what is before **String3** is ***String1*** and what is after *String2* is **String3**
Obs2. Remember that the extension need to remain unchanged.

'Expected Inputs' => 'Expected Outputs' 

'Bakemonogatari Ost Classmate.mp3' => 'Classmate Bakemonogatari Ost.mp3' 
'Bakemonogatari Ost Date.mp3' => 'Date Bakemonogatari Ost.mp3' 
'Bakemonogatari Ost Dokuzetsu.mp3' => 'Dokuzetsu Bakemonogatari Ost.mp3' 
'Bakemonogatari Ost Kedamono.mp3' => 'Kedamono Bakemonogatari Ost.mp3' 
'Hanamonogatari ost Nattoku.mp3' => 'Nattoku Hanamonogatari ost.mp3' 
'Kizumonogatari ost Preface.mp3' => 'Preface Kizumonogatari ost.mp3' 
'Kizumonogatari ost Reprise.mp3' => 'Reprise Kizumonogatari ost.mp3' 
'Koimonogatari ost Jigoku no Sata mo Kane Shidai.mp3' => 'Jigoku no Sata mo Kane Shidai Koimonogatari ost.mp3' 
'Koimonogatari ost Namakemono no Sekkubataraki.mp3' => 'Namakemono no Sekkubataraki Koimonogatari ost.mp3' 
'Nisemonogatari ost Bangs.mp3' => 'Bangs Nisemonogatari ost.mp3' 
'Nisemonogatari ost Story.mp3' => 'Story Nisemonogatari ost Bangs.mp3' 
'Nisemonogatari ost Unrest.mp3' => 'Unrest Nisemonogatari ost Bangs.mp3' 

Resolution by user43791:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# You can adjust the pattern "*.mp3" to match a different file extension or a different directory if needed - user43791
for i in *.mp3; do
    # Keep the path - user43791
    p="$(dirname "$i")"

    if [[ ${i##*/} =~ ^(.*gatari)\ +([Oo]st)\ +(.*)(\.[^.]+)$ ]]; then
        # Content of BASH_REMATCH: - user43791
        # [1] from start until the end of monogatari - user43791
        # [2] Ost or ost - user43791
        # [3] Everything after ost/Ost until (and not including) the last dot - user43791
        # [4] The extension (.mp3) - user43791
    mv "$i" "$p/${BASH_REMATCH[3]} ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    fi

    #I repeated the loop for the others patterns that i finded after the response by user43791 in the files - Rodrigo

    if [[ ${i##*/} =~ ^(.*iro)\ +([Oo]st)\ +(.*)(\.[^.]+)$ ]]; then
    mv "$i" "$p/${BASH_REMATCH[3]} ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    fi
    if [[ ${i##*/} =~ ^(.*uro)\ +([Oo]st)\ +(.*)(\.[^.]+)$ ]]; then
    mv "$i" "$p/${BASH_REMATCH[3]} ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    fi
    if [[ ${i##*/} =~ ^(.*II)\ +([Oo]st)\ +(.*)(\.[^.]+)$ ]]; then
    mv "$i" "$p/${BASH_REMATCH[3]} ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    fi
    if [[ ${i##*/} =~ ^(.*lll)\ +([Oo]st)\ +(.*)(\.[^.]+)$ ]]; then
        mv "$i" "$p/${BASH_REMATCH[3]} ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    fi
    if [[ ${i##*/} =~ ^(.*eason)\ +([Oo]st)\ +(.*)(\.[^.]+)$ ]]; then
        mv "$i" "$p/${BASH_REMATCH[3]} ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: IIUC XFCE Thunar had builtin feature for that. One could use regex to *group* part of file name string and use it in replace mode.

Comment: Thank you for all the pictures and clear description, but you need to append [a text-only version of those images to your question](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086). Ideally, to *every* file in the listing, show the expected new name of that file. This is specially useful for the one with various spaces.

Comment: Your colored annotations are confusing to my eyes. Please replace your images with a text-only version of your question.

Comment: Thank for warning me about the images, i didn't know, sorry and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `bash` only answer, according to your specifications, you might be able to get away with something as simple as this:

```bsh
# You can adjust the pattern "*.mp3" to match a different file extension or a different directory if needed
for i in *.mp3; do
    # Keep the path
    p="$(dirname "$i")"

    if [[ ${i##*/} =~ ^(.*monogatari)\ +([Oo]st)\ +(.*)(\.[^.]+)$ ]]; then
        # Content of BASH_REMATCH:
        # [1] from start until the end of monogatari
        # [2] Ost or ost
        # [3] Everything after ost/Ost until (and not including) the last dot
        # [4] The extension (.mp3)
        mv "$i" "$p/${BASH_REMATCH[3]} ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    fi
done
```

**Note: All this code is untested, make sure you check that it works by putting `echo` before `mv` before running it.**

Comment: `p` will always be `.` in your code, unless you have a file whose name begins with a dash, in which case you will get errors, both from `dirname` and from `mv`.

Comment: I had to make some changes in the code because a found another patterns in the String1, but the code worked perfectly, I just copied e pasted the loop, changing the (.*monogatari) for the others patterns, but thank you all so much!!!

Comment: @Kusalananda Depends if the pattern is changed to something that contains a directory